# How to run a sample qt application inside a ubuntu container

Tags: qt, lxc

i am reasearcher of LXC.I would like to run a qt sample application inside my ubuntu container.Before trying it inside container,i tried the same in my ubuntu machine which is the host for container and it was successfully.But when i tried inside the container it shows the error as could not connect to display,precisely the ERROR:"Qxcbconnection: could not connect to display".How can access the display device from container.Does X11 forwading will help in this situation??if yes how can i use it.

Please do support

Comment: https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/is-it-possible-to-run-xwindow-in-a-container/2668/2